# how to remove the toolbaritem from master detail page for current page only in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using 'Master Detail Page' for sidebar menu.

I want to remove the green marked home icon(toolbaritems) on right side from only one page. How to do this. Anyone please help to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some code of master page and detail page where you want to remove so its more helpful to solve your issue

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <MasterDetailPage xmlns="xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"; xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"; x:Class="MyProjectName.App.View.MasterDetailPage1" xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyProjectName.App.View"> <MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems> <ToolbarItem Priority="0" Order="Primary" Icon="homeicon.png" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"></ToolbarItem> </MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems> <MasterDetailPage.Master> <pages:MasterDetailPage1Master x:Name="MasterPage" /> </MasterDetailPage.Master>